# how to use WSAConnect and WSAAccept for sending receving init Data before accept a request

Tags: windows, visual-c++, winsock2

As title, I 've searched in msdn or on internet for an example but I didn't find any one >_<
All case they use  WSAConnect ( S, sa, sa_len ,**NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL** );
I wanna use those function (WSAConnect & WSAAccept) for a simple authority with key in lpCallerData->buf before accept
I 've tried the example about WSAAccept from msdn for server side and my simple code about WSAConnect but It's alway "lpCallerData == NULL"
Sorry about my bad english
Thank you in advance with any help!

My not working code:

Server side:

```
SOCKET              SV_Socket;
struct sockaddr_in  SV_Channel;
WORD                SV_wVersionRequested;
WSADATA             SV_wsaData;
int                 SV_on = 1;

int CALLBACK ConditionAcceptFunc(
    LPWSABUF lpCallerId,
    LPWSABUF lpCallerData,
    LPQOS pQos,
    LPQOS lpGQOS,
    LPWSABUF lpCalleeId,
    LPWSABUF lpCalleeData,
    GROUP FAR * g,
    DWORD_PTR dwCallbackData
    )
{
    //printf( "test1\n" );

    //if ( memcmp( lpCallerData->buf ,"quyen194" , lpCallerData->len ) == 0 ) 
    if ( lpCallerData->buf[0] == 'q' ) 
    {

        //memcpy( lpCalleeData->buf ,"OK" ,2 );
        //lpCalleeData->len = 2;

        return CF_ACCEPT;
    }
    else
    {
        //printf( "Reject request: \n" );
        //printf( "Buf: " );
        //printf( lpCallerData->buf );
        //printf( "\nLen: %d\n" ,lpCallerData->len );
        //memcpy( lpCalleeData->buf ,"NOT" ,3 );
        return CF_REJECT;
    }
}
void AcceptRequest()
{
    struct sockaddr_in saClient;
    int iClientSize = sizeof(saClient);


//---- ACCEPT connection ------------------
    while(true){
        int socketNumb = 0;
        if(AcceptRequestFunctionLogOnScreen)
            if(AllSuccessLogOnScreen)
                printf("%d: Data Transfer Listen Socket Waiting...\n",socketNumb);



        //C_Socket = accept(SV_Socket,NULL,NULL);   // block for connection request 
        C_Socket = WSAAccept(SV_Socket, (SOCKADDR*) &saClient, &iClientSize, &ConditionAcceptFunc, NULL);



        if(C_Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            if(AcceptRequestFunctionLogOnScreen)
                if(AllErrorLogOnScreen)
                    printf("%d: Data Transfer Listen Socket accept failed with error: %ld\n",socketNumb,WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
        }
        else{
            if(AcceptRequestFunctionLogOnScreen)
                if(AllSuccessLogOnScreen)
                    printf("%d: Request to Data Transfer Listen Socket Accepted...\n",socketNumb);
            //Mark that Client Socket is inused
            C_Alive = true;
            //---- SEND bytes -------------------------------------------
            CreateThread(NULL,NULL,LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(DataSending),NULL,NULL,NULL);
            CreateThread(NULL,NULL,LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(DataReceiving),NULL,NULL,NULL);
            while(C_Alive == true){
                Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
    }   

    while(shutdown(SV_Socket,SD_BOTH)){
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    closesocket(SV_Socket);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}
```

Client side:

```
void Connect2Server()
{
    struct sockaddr_in saClient;
    int iClientSize = sizeof(saClient);
    LPWSABUF lpCallerData= new(WSABUF);
    //WSABUF lpCalleeData;// = new(WSABUF);

    lpCallerData->buf[0] = 'q';
    lpCallerData->len = 1;
        printf( "Source: \n" );
        printf( "Buf: " );
        printf( lpCallerData->buf );
        printf( "\nLen: %d\n" ,lpCallerData->len );

    system("pause");
    //---- try CONNECT -----------------------------------------
    int ReturnValue;
    int TryToConnect;
    int One_socketNumb = 0;
    for(TryToConnect=0;TryToConnect<=10;TryToConnect++)
    {
        //ReturnValue = connect(C_Socket,(SOCKADDR *)&C_Channel, sizeof(C_Channel));

        ReturnValue = WSAConnect( C_Socket ,(SOCKADDR *)&C_Channel ,sizeof(C_Channel) ,lpCallerData ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL );

        //printf( "Result: \n" );
        //printf( "Buf: " );
        //printf( lpCalleeData->buf );
        //printf( "Len: %d\n" ,lpCalleeData->len );

        if (ReturnValue == SOCKET_ERROR){
            if(Connect2ServerFunctionLogOnScreen)
                if(AllErrorLogOnScreen){
                    printf("%d: Connect error %ld",One_socketNumb,WSAGetLastError());
                    printf("%d: Attempt to connect #%d to ChatP2P Server\n",One_socketNumb,TryToConnect+1);
                }
            Sleep(1000);
            if (TryToConnect == 10)
            {
                WSACleanup();
                return; //Couldn't connect
            }
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------   
    if(Connect2ServerFunctionLogOnScreen)
        if(AllSuccessLogOnScreen)
            printf("%d: Connect ServerSOCKET: OK...\n",One_socketNumb);
    //Mark that Server Socket is inused
    C_Alive = true;

    //---Connection OK
    if(Connect2ServerFunctionLogOnScreen)
        if(AllSuccessLogOnScreen)
            printf("\n%d: Connected\n",One_socketNumb);
    //---- SEND bytes -------------------------------------------
    CreateThread(NULL,NULL,LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(DataSending),NULL,NULL,NULL);
    CreateThread(NULL,NULL,LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(DataReceiving),NULL,NULL,NULL);
    while(C_Alive == true){
        Sleep(10000);
    }
    //---Close Client Socket----------
    shutdown(C_Socket,SD_BOTH);
    closesocket(C_Socket);
    //-------------------------------------

    if(Connect2ServerFunctionLogOnScreen)
        if(AllSuccessLogOnScreen)
            printf("%d: Disconnected\n",One_socketNumb);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lpCallerData` is always NULL in your `WSAAccept()` callback because TCP/IP does not support exchanging caller/callee data during connection establishment.  This is clearly stated in the `WSAConnect()` documentation:

> **Note** Connect data is not supported by the TCP/IP protocol in Windows. Connect data is supported only on ATM (RAWWAN) over a raw socket.

The `WSAAccept()` documentation also states:

> If no caller identification **or caller data** is available, the corresponding parameters will be NULL. **Many network protocols do not support connect-time caller data**.
>
> ...
>
> The lpCalleeData->len initially contains the length of the buffer allocated by the service provider and pointed to by lpCalleeData->buf. **A value of zero means passing user data back to the caller is not supported**.

With that said, even if it were supported, you are not managing the `WSABUF` structures correctly anyway.  Your server is not checking for NULL or `len` overflows, and your client code is not allocating any memory for the `WSABUF::buf` fields.

Your code would need to look more like this instead:

Server side:

```
int CALLBACK ConditionAcceptFunc(
    LPWSABUF lpCallerId,
    LPWSABUF lpCallerData,
    LPQOS pQos,
    LPQOS lpGQOS,
    LPWSABUF lpCalleeId,
    LPWSABUF lpCalleeData,
    GROUP FAR * g,
    DWORD_PTR dwCallbackData
    )
{
    //printf( "test1\n" );

    //if ((lpCallerData) && (lpCallerData->len >= 8) && (memcmp(lpCallerData->buf, "quyen194", 8) == 0)) 
    if ((lpCallerData) && (lpCallerData->len > 0) && (lpCallerData->buf[0] == 'q')) 
    {
        //if ((lpCalleeData) && (lpCalleeData->len > 0)) {
        //  memcpy( lpCalleeData->buf, "OK", 2 );
        //  lpCalleeData->len = 2;
        //}

        return CF_ACCEPT;
    }
    else
    {
        //printf( "Reject request: \n" );
        //if ((lpCallerData) && (lpCallerData->len > 0)) {
        //  printf( "Buf: %*s", lpCallerData->len, lpCallerData->buf );
        //  printf( "\nLen: %d\n", lpCallerData->len );
        //}
        //if ((lpCalleeData) && (lpCalleeData->len > 0)) {
        //  memcpy( lpCalleeData->buf, "NOT", 3 );
        //  lpCalleeData->len = 3;
        //}

        return CF_REJECT;
    }
}
```

Client side:

```
void Connect2Server()
{
    ...

    WSABUF CallerData;
    WSABUF CalleeData;

    char CallerBuf = 'q';
    CallerData.buf = &CallerBuf;
    CallerData.len = 1;

    char CalleeBuf[12] = {0};
    CalleeData.buf = CalleeBuf;
    CalleeData.len = 12;

    printf( "Source: \n" );
    printf( "Buf: %*s", CallerData.len, CallerData.buf );
    printf( "\nLen: %d\n", CallerData.len );

    ...

    ReturnValue = WSAConnect( C_Socket, (SOCKADDR *)&C_Channel, sizeof(C_Channel), &CallerData, &CalleeData, NULL, NULL );

    //printf( "Result: \n" );
    //printf( "Buf: %*s", CalleeData.len, CalleeData.buf );
    //printf( "Len: %d\n", CalleeData.len );

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Could you please do me an one more favour? I do not know how to use TransmitPackets function and TransmitFile function >_< I can't find out any example about it! Could you share me a simple example how to use it in client side and server side? if you do not have much time, just write it as simple as you want :D Thank you again