# Program crashes when trying to retrieve contents of pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, winapi, winsock, winsock2

I'm making a socket program in C++ using `winsock2` and I'm trying to use `WSAAccept` to conditionally accept connections. I copied the example [ConditionalFunction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741513(v=vs.85).aspx#code-snippet-2) from MSDN for the `lpfnCondition` argument in WSAAccept as seen below.

```
SOCKET WSAAccept(
  _In_    SOCKET          s,
  _Out_   struct sockaddr *addr,
  _Inout_ LPINT           addrlen,
  _In_    LPCONDITIONPROC lpfnCondition, //<---------
  _In_    DWORD_PTR       dwCallbackData
);
```

However when trying to access the contents of `lpCallerId` in the `ConditionalFunction` like so `WSABUF buffer = *lpCallerData` my program crashes. I know this is the source of the problem because when I comment that line out my program doesn't crash. I don't think all of my code would be necessary. Any help would be lovely.

EDIT:

```
CALLBACK ConditionalAccept(LPWSABUF lpCallerId,LPWSABUF lpCallerData,LPQOS lpSQOS,
                           LPQOS lpGQOS,LPWSABUF lpCalleeId,LPWSABUF lpCalleeData,
                           GROUP *g,DWORD_PTR dwCallbackData)
{
    WSABUF buffer = *lpCallerData;

    if (lpSQOS != NULL) {
        RtlZeroMemory(lpSQOS, sizeof(QOS));
        return CF_ACCEPT;
    } else
        return CF_REJECT;
}
```

...

```
WSAAccept(slisten, (SOCKADDR*)&acceptSock, &Size, &ConditionalAccept, NULL);
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us.

Comment: What is `lpCallerData`?

Comment: If you can read the MSDN document regarding this parameter: The information in these parameters is sent along with the connection request. *If no caller identification or caller data is available, the corresponding parameters will be NULL*.

Comment: @LukeLee I don't understand why trying to retrieve the contents of a `NULL` variable would make my program crash.

Comment: @immibis `lpCallerData` is, as stated on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741513(v=vs.85).aspx#code-snippet-2) "The lpCallerData is a value parameter that contains any user data."

Comment: Related: [how to use WSAConnect and WSAAccept for sending receving init Data before accept a request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247621/). `lpCallerData` is **always** NULL in TCP/IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Luke stated, you are not checking `lpCallerData` for NULL before dereferencing it.  That is why your code is crashing.

```
int CALLBACK ConditionalAccept(LPWSABUF lpCallerId,LPWSABUF lpCallerData,LPQOS lpSQOS,
                           LPQOS lpGQOS,LPWSABUF lpCalleeId,LPWSABUF lpCalleeData,
                           GROUP *g,DWORD_PTR dwCallbackData)
{
    WSABUF buffer = {0};

    if (lpCallerData != NULL) { // <-- add this check!
        buffer = *lpCallerData;
    }

    if (lpSQOS != NULL) {
        RtlZeroMemory(lpSQOS, sizeof(QOS));
        return CF_ACCEPT;
    } else
        return CF_REJECT;
}
```

However, `lpCallerData` is meaningless in TCP/IP and will **always** be NULL.  TCP/IP does not support exchanging caller/callee data during connection establishment. This is clearly stated in the [`WSAConnect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741559.aspx) documentation:

> The `lpCallerData` parameter contains a pointer to any user data that is to be sent along with the connection request (called connect data). This is additional data, not in the normal network data stream, that is sent with network requests to establish a connection. This option is used by legacy protocols such as DECNet, OSI TP4, and others.
>
> **Note Connect data is not supported by the TCP/IP protocol in Windows. Connect data is supported only on ATM (RAWWAN) over a raw socket.**